# Display:table : how to add an attribute to a row

Tags: jsp, taglib, displaytag

I would like to add a tooltip (attribute title) to a row in a table.
This table is build in a jsp with the taglib display:table and look like this (simplified).

```
<display:table class="list" id="row" name="listResultat" decorator="dyndecorator">
    <display:column property="dateEnvoieDt" title="Date envoi" ></display:column>
<display:table>
```

The generated code is :

```
<table id="row" style="width:100%;" class="list" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="orderSortable sortable sorted order1">Date envoi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>19</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I would like to add a title like this :

```
<tr class="odd" title="18">
...
<tr class="even" title="19">
```

I tried with a decorator but I don't find a way to do it.
Can someone help ?

Comment: What taglib does `<display:...>` refer to?

Comment: it referes to displaytag

Answer (score 0):

I added a span inside each display:column, but it is not clean.

```
<display:column property="dateEnvoieDt" title="Date envoi" >
    <span title='<bean:write name="codeAno"/>'>
        <bean:write name="row" property="dateEnvoieDt" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
    </span>
</display:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add a title attribute to a row (`tr` element) by "injecting" it into the `TableDecorator`'s `addRowClass()` method:

```
public class MyTableDecorator extends TableDecorator {
  @Override
  public String addRowClass() {
    return "these are css classes\" title=\"this is the title";
  }
}
```

(take into account that displaytag will add the double quotes for you.)